# Duplicate database to roll back theme & content changes

Tags: database, wp-config, phpmyadmin

I am going to update site to a new custom theme and it will take a few days to get all the work done. Can I duplicate a wp database in phpMYadmin, so i have wp-db1 and wp-db2. Then I can change wp-config to use db2 while i am updating the site theme but when I run out of time for the day, i can change wp-config to use the original db1 and switch back and forth between the two. Is that possible or just a pipe dream on my end? All theme settings are saved in the DB so why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

That will work - as long as you're the only user. If other users have access to the site you'd also have to port over their work to the other database. If that's the case, you may want to copy your entire website to a staging site, make the changes there, and once changes are complete push everything (database and files, assuming files are also necessary) to the live site.

Comment: Thanks web elaine. I am the only one. I deved it on a staging site but there's so much custom stuff in the content I need to go page by page to change stuff over. previous build used a 'site builder' for page content which is trash shortcodes etc and each page needs to be checked. There are some integrations with api's that i can't set up on a localhost any way either but I think this is the best way to deploy over the next few days in the off hours.

Comment: You may also want to look into https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316939/how-can-i-develop-a-new-theme-in-wordpress-without-disrupting-the-current-site/316942#316944